# Connecting to ActiveMQ "Classic" using SSL with self-signed certs

Tags: java, activemq-classic, broker

How can I setup SSL on ActiveMQ server?

I followed [this tutorial](https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl) to create certificate for ActiveMQ.

1. Using keytool, create a certificate for the broker:

   ```
   keytool -genkey -alias broker -keyalg RSA -keystore amq-server.ks
   ```
2. Export the broker’s certificate so it can be shared with clients:

   ```
   keytool -export -alias broker -keystore broker.ks -file amq- server_cert
   ```
3. Create a certificate/keystore for the client:

   ```
   keytool -genkey -alias client -keyalg RSA -keystore amq-server.ks
   ```
4. Create a truststore for the client, and import the broker’s certificate. This establishes that client "trusts" the broker:

   ```
   keytool -import -alias broker -keystore client.ts -file amq-server_cert
   ```

I have Ubuntu Server with ActiveMQ and Windows Machine with MQTT.fx.

I added that setting in ActiveMQ config:

```xml
<transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
<transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61714?transport.enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2"/`
```

I installed now on a machine MQTT.fx, and I'm trying to connect over SSL. I created 2 configs - one with a certificate and other without a certificate. Connecting works without certificate. Connection with certificate does not work. I have selected the server certificate or the client certificate does not work.

If I add this setting to ActiveMQ config then nothing works anymore

```xml
<sslContext> 
   <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.base}/conf/amq-server.ks" 
               keyStorePassword="password"
               trustStore="file:${activemq.base}/conf/amq-server.ts"
               trustStorePassword="password"/> 
</sslContext>
```

I have tried all combinations does not work.

Can someone help me? How can I just set up SSL on ActiveMQ and communicate with certificate. Maybe one way SSL?

Comment: If you're using MQTT you might consider using [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) rather than "Classic" (i.e. 5.x) because, among other things, Artemis has support for MQTT 5 and "Classic" does not. You can find more details in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/mqtt.html).

Answer (score 0):

In step #3 you should be using this command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias client -keyalg RSA -keystore client.ts
```

Notice that this command uses `client.ts` rather than `amq-server.ks`. This will be the truststore that you use on MQTT.fx.

Also, if you're using MQTT with and without SSL you should add the proper `transportConnector` elements and use those from your MQTT application(s), e.g.:

```xml
<transportConnector name="mqtt+nio" uri="mqtt+nio://0.0.0.0:1883"/>
<transportConnector name="mqtt+nio" uri="mqtt+nio+ssl://0.0.0.0:8883"/>
```

Your `sslContext` should be configured as follows:

```xml
<sslContext>
    <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.conf}/amq-server.ks" keyStorePassword="password"/>
</sslContext>
```

Comment: it still doesn't  work. On the activemq server, folder opt/activemq/conf, I have the following files: amq-client_cert, amq-client.ks, amq-server.ts, amq-server_cert. On client Machine I have the following files: amq-client.ks, amq-client.ts, amq-server_cert, amq-client_cert. I modified activemq config file. It doesn't work with or without a certificate. I do not know anymore.

Comment: i get the error message: `io.netty.channel.Abstract$AnnotatedConnectionException_Connection refuses: no further information:/BrokerIP:1883`

Comment: The *only* SSL-related file you need in the broker's `conf` directory is the keystore (i.e. `amq-server.ks`). This is what you reference from the `sslContext` configuration in `activemq.xml`. Likewise, the *only* SSL-related file you need on the client is the truststore (i.e. `amq-client.ts`). This is what you'd reference in your MQTT.fx connection configuration.

Comment: Where are you seeing that `AnnotatedConnectionException_Connection`? Is it on the client or in the broker's log?

Comment: i use mqttfx 5.3.0, 
in mqttfx I can only choose these optins for the SSL Communication, which are: ` Enable ssl/tls (yes or not) , Protokol Version (SSl1,2,3 or TLSv1,2,3), Key Algorithm, and either Default ca certificate; CA certificate file , Ca certificate keystore, Certificates file, ca certfifikate fron trusted keystore.`
in mqttfx on the cleint Machine I dont have the possibility to choose keystore.  The Message. The error message appears when i try to communicate in mqttfx via ssl from the cleint.

Comment: I don't know if there is another way to implement it or am I just doing Something wrong, I would be grateful for any kind of help. regard

Comment: Given that MQTT.fx appears to be closed source and has no public documentation I'm afraid I can't help you with any issues there. Could you use a different MQTT tool (e.g. Mosquitto tools)?

Comment: Which one would you recommend for me? i would like to test the communication with and without ssl for later deployment.

Comment: I don't quite understand your use-case. Are you saying you want some tools to do a quick test of MQTT with and without SSL before you deploy the broker to production?

Comment: I would like to test it first to understand how it works and to use it on a few machines in the future.